# Store console output into file using java

Tags: java

I am using jcraft for connect with UNIX i have done successfully all code but current the response show on console screen and  my need  is store in the sum specific file or its show on any other frame type

Comment: @JvdBerg i tried to connect unix server with windows system, i have done all the code , but my problem is the unix server response show on console and i need to show that output on frame

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a logging framework like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/). You can configure different outputs of your logs then.

However I'm not sure what you are actually printing on your console.

Comment: i just connect unix server using java in windows the all response show on console and i need that output will be shown on any frame or panel